# Too much white space after large equation in memoir class

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment

I'm currently writing my thesis using the **memoir class** and I have experienced some unwanted behavior when typing large equations. LaTeX adds a ridiculous amount of vertical white space to place the equation number when the equation itself is page-wide.

An example: the following code

```
This is an example of the ridiculous amount of white space added:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
eqn_1 &= a + b + \cdots \quad \text{(just typing a page-wide equation here)} \quad \cdots + y+z\\
eqn_2 &= \text{(another equation)}\\
\vdots& \\
\vdots & \\
eqn_n &= \text{(the last equation)}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
How to fix it?
```

leads to the following outcome:

[image: <code>Example of added white space</code>]

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you!

Comment: why are you using align here? you have no alignment point and only one row???

Comment: That much space looks like a page breaking issue.  You should post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497).

Comment: You might want to change the title as this has nothing to do with the `memoir` class. Change it to something more suitable to your question, such such that it is useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is too wide, causing the number to be placed below, rather than adjacent to, the equation. You must strive to break the long (full-width) line into multiple, shorter lines.

Also, as David noted, there is no need for the outer `align`, as you only have one row to align.  I replaced with the `equation` environment.

I propose doing this by way of `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is an example of the ridiculous amount of white space added:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
eqn_1 &=\begin{aligned}[t] & a + b + \cdots \quad 
    \text{(just typing a page-wide equation here)}\\
  & \cdots + y+z\end{aligned}\\
eqn_2 &= \text{(another equation)}\\
\vdots& \\
\vdots & \\
eqn_n &= \text{(the last equation)}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
How to fix it?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Steven for the suggestion, however, this does not remove the excessive amount of vertical white space added right after the entire equation.

Comment: @Ashes Then you need to provide not just a snippet of code, but a full (but small) code example, beginning with `\documentclass`, which demonstrates the issue.  You may edit your question to achieve this.

Comment: @Ashes see the image posted here `How to fix it?` comes straight after the equation, what space are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the huge space. However, it's possible to move up the equation number by reducing the display's width.

Also, you're misusing `cases`: the alignment point is for stating conditions, not for aligning the right-hand side of equations.

This is solved by nesting `aligned` in `cases`.

Next, split the overlong expression with the help of `mathtools` and its `multlined` environment.

Don't use `align` for single equations (and `cases` counts as one).

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

This is an example of the ridiculous amount of white space added:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
eqn_1 &= \begin{multlined}[t]
         a + b + \dots \text{(just typing a page-wide equation here)}\\
         +\dots + y+z
         \end{multlined}\\
eqn_2 &= \text{(another equation)}\\
\vdots& \\
\vdots & \\
eqn_n &= \text{(the last equation)}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
How to fix it?

\end{document}
```

[image]